# How do I suppress the local country on address labels?

Tags: 4.6.2, address-labels

I tried to apply [this solution](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=18576.0) to allow me to suppress the country field on address labels for my own country, using the 4.6.2 CiviCRM release. I successfully used this on the project when I built it a year or so ago but it does not work any more, even allowing for line number changes in the current version. Can anyone advise what I need to do to get it working again? Go to say I'm not sure which version it got broken in as I'd forgotten to apply it the last couple of times I upgraded but someone else in our organisation pointed it out to me earlier today.

Answer (score 3):

This extension
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken

Has a token called 'Conditional country' - which does that
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken/blob/master/tokens/address.inc#L7

You can use the token in the mailing label
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address?reset=1